# How could I deploy independent services in a SOA stack? Java EE based

Tags: jakarta-ee, architecture, soa

I have a Web-Service stack in Java EE, and I have a problem: everytime I need change a specific service, deploy and restart the application, the others one need to be restarted too.

I would like to know if there is some architecture (open-source) to deploy my services in separated contexts. I want to create a SOA structure.

In a logical thinking: create an application for each webservice. But, I really believe that exists an easier alternative.

I need to audit each service (duration time, enter parameters, result, if it got error)

What you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't supply a lot of details but if you have real services (i.e independent components that communicate via interfaces) there is no real reason to have them in the same application anyway.

More so, having each service in its own application allows you to change, scale etc. each one  independently form the others and gives you added flexibility vs. having them in one app

Comment: Sure, but how could I wrap them with Auditing, Logging, Caching, etc. in this model ?

Comment: logging and caching are not services - these are,typically, shared libraries (used by each service separately. Auditing can be a service if you make your services notify it (e.g. it subscribes to all messages). Services doesn't mean that everything is a service

Comment: Ok, let me redo it. Should the responsability to do auditing, logging, caching... be of the service or the core-architecture?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what requirement you have on your runtime environment.

Typically you group such services into applications, if there are too many to handle as separate applications. If you have a set of services that are related, such as "Order services", "financial services", "logistics services" or what have you.

When you need to change one, there is a high possibility you also need to make changes in related services, such as updating schemas or what not. In this case all services won't need to be restarted, just a "group" (application).

There are also tailor made containers for those situations, specifically for services in the integration layer.

I'm thinking of [Apache Service Mix](http://servicemix.apache.org/) which deploys SOA services as OSGi bundles that are easy to handle, separate from each other.

It should be possible to deploy web applications if you alter the configuration and packaging a bit.